# Where does macports add itself to PATH?

Tags: macports, path

I've just installed macports. The `postflight` script has somehow modified my PATH variable so that the macports binaries now take precedence in ways I don't like. For example, it has downgraded `rustc`.

I've tried to find out where macports has added itself to the path. I couldn't find any mention of `/opt/local/bin` anywhere in `~/.zshrc` and the like.

Neither did looking in macports docs help.

Comment: It is documented on the macports install instructions page https://www.macports.org/install.php which links to https://guide.macports.org/#installing.shell for details - where would you want it documented.

Comment: @mmmmmmm It says about as much as I knew and put in the question. There's no mention at all of `.zprofile`, the most common file to be modified on modern macOS.

Comment: second paragraph on "macOS Package (.pkg) Inst" says -  If needed your shell configuration files will be adapted by the installer.

Comment: Indeed, but the documentation says: `Depending on your shell and which configuration files already exist, the installer may use .profile, .bash_login, .bash_profile, .tcshrc, or .cshrc.` - `.zprofile` is glaringly missing and should be added.

Comment: Fair point......

Comment: I've opened a PR to add that one file to the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it in `~/.zprofile`:

```
##
# Your previous /Users/xxx/.zprofile file was backed up as /Users/xxx/.zprofile.macports-saved_2023-12-24_at_02:48:28
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2023-12-24_at_02:48:28: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


# MacPorts Installer addition on 2023-12-24_at_02:48:28: adding an appropriate MANPATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export MANPATH="/opt/local/share/man:$MANPATH"
# Finished adapting your MANPATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```